# Make sure content inside of relative element is behaving properly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with regarding of `position: relative;`. If I use it then all the content inside of it is has weird width and it is not scaling in regards to elements.

Better to show an example. Here I have a simple pop-up navigation that is showing when I hover over a link.

1. I want the navigation to be showing underneath the link
2. I want the navigation items underneath to be positioned correctly (not under each other)

Solution is to use JavaScript and on hover get the position of the link and place the underlying elements into correct position. I don't like this approach too much so I wonder if there is a different way.

You can comment out the `$(this).find('.container').css('left', left);` line to see what I'm talking about.

```js
// I don't want to use JavaScript but it seems the only way
$(function() {
  $('.link').on('mouseover', function() {
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    $(this).find('.container').css('left', left);
  });
});


// If .link will be "position: relative;" then the red blocks will be positioned wrongly (down)
// If I use JavaScript then... ..well.. then I use JavaScript
```

```css
.link {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* position: relative; */
}
.link:hover .container {
  display: block;
}
.link .container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 112px;
  display: none;
}
.link .container .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkgvrtnn/

Comment: [mcve] in your question. With 9K rep you should know this.

Comment: @j08691 There is a fiddle with commented code/css. And the reason I didn't put the code here is because SO doesn't support SCSS.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. However what if jsFiddle goes away? Or is down? Or is blocked by my company's firewall? Your question should have everything needed to resolve it *within the question*, and shouldn't require any of us to visit a third-party site to see your code example.

Comment: @j08691 Specially for you :)

Comment: Setting `position:relative` makes the parent the reference point for the absolute positioning - and that means, the default width in which the element is laid out is that of the parent. If you can specify the appropriate width for the `.container` elements upfront, that should fix it.

Comment: See, that wasn't so hard now was it? And you got a +1 from me.

Comment: @CBroe No, that is not an option. The `.container` elements are dynamic and I don't know the width beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the left:0px;

```
.link .container {
  position: absolute;
  //left: 0px;
  margin-top: 112px;
  display: none;
}
```

Which is causing for the block to be locked at the left side of the outside container, if you add the relative position to .link, it will align correctly, but the problem is that container will inherit its width.... so therefore it would not have auto width, which you want.

So you either remove the left and rely on the outer most container width, or use javascript, because you would need to have a fixed .container width to achieve this.

Comment: Well, actually all i had to do is remove `left: 0px;` and nothing else.